# Using JQuery to add a triangle to the bottom of a div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a long div, of which I wish to style by attaching a triangle to the bottom. How can I do this using just JQuery and CSS?

```
$(".mini-filter-xs").prepend("<div class='filter-flag' style='width=100%; background-color:#37BDD1'>Hello There! <diV>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: [CSS Tricks - CSS Triangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

CSS triangle (arrow up):

```
.arrow-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var divTriangle = $("<div/>").addClass("arrow-up");
// Append divTriangle to your bottom element
$("#yourBottomElement").append(divTriangle);
```